# Is there an option for a Simulink Scope to display the layout in single column?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I mean like in the picture from below, for example if I'm having more than 4 layouts to have all of them in a single line, not in a matrix.
Does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can have up to 16x16 subplots in a scope. By default, the 4x4 grid is shown when pressing the layout button, but if you click and hold your mouse in this grid, you can expand this:

[image]